Embedded device with RS485 and LORA
I'm looking to build an embedded device for an industrial scenario. Beyond running linux, it just needs RS485 connectivity, and LORA.  LORA via a hat is acceptable. Minimal storage requirements. No other interfaces required.
An RPi would work, but seems overkill. I'm looking for something cheaper, but still robust.
Appreciate any pointers.
